# Scheduled Tasks - ERROR: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password

Tags: batch-file, cmd, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008, windows-task-scheduler

In Win 2003 servers, I used to run the below command in a batch file and get the list of all scheduled tasks in other servers in our environment remotely.

```
schtasks /query /fo list /v /s server2003 /u user /p pwd >> "%outfile%"
```

User in the above command is setup as a local account for all servers. It is also the author of all scheduled tasks.

Recently we upgraded some of our server to Win 2008 from 2003 and the above command stopped working. I tried below mentioned things but they're throwing me unknown username or pwd error.

```
schtasks /query /fo list /v /s server2008 /u user@server2008 /p pwd >> "%outfile%"
schtasks /query /fo list /v /s server2008 /u server2008\user /p pwd >> "%outfile%"
```

Now I also have a domain account which has access to all server so I tried the below command:

```
schtasks /query /fo list /v /s server2008 /u Domain_UserName /p Domain_pwd >> "%outfile%"
```

This is giving me only a set of scheduled tasks, for which the task_owner is system and not the local user. So how to extract all tasks remotely in this context? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the local user password contain any symbols that might have special meaning to cmd, such as `& | < > ^ %`?  You can do `/p "password"` enclosed in quotation marks if you wish, and the quotation marks won't be evaluated as part of the password.  So if the password were `re1ndeer&fl0ti11a`, you'd use `/p "re1ndeer&fl0ti11a"` to prevent the & symbol from truncating the command.

Comment: @rojo The password contains $ sign. I tried your suggestion but it did not work as it's still giving me the same error. I also checked the firewall settings if something is blocking but the firewalls are turned off so no problem there.

Comment: Not sure whether this'll make any difference, but you could `set "user=computername\localuser"` [\n] `set "pass=pa$$word"` [\n] `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` [\n] `schtasks /query /fo list /v /s computername /u !user! /p !pass! >>"%outfile%"` [\n] `endlocal` just to remove all doubt.  If that doesn't work, you might hack a workaround with `wmic /node:remotePC /user:remotePC\user /password:pass job list /format:list >>outfile` until someone has a better idea.  Or you might ask on serverfault.